# Что такое прототип?

Tags: javascript

Не могу сам разобраться что такое прототип в javascript, подскажите что это такое.

---

в книге с носорогом (Дэвид Флэнаган) написано

7.4.7. Метод `isPrototypeOf()`
Метод `isPrototypeOf()` возвращает `true`, если объект, которому принадлежит метод, является прототипом объекта, передаваемого методу в качестве аргумента.
В противном случае метод возвращает `false`. Например:

```
var o = {};
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(o);        // true: o.constructor == Object
Object.isPrototypeOf(o);                  // false
o.isPrototypeOf(Object.prototype);        // false
Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Object); // true: Object.constructor == Function
```

Comment: можете развернуть вопрос? что за прототип имеется ввиду?

Comment: @Grundy обновил вопрос

Comment: а в данной книге до этой главы разве не было определения прототипа? что это и зачем?

Comment: @Grundy, самое смешное, что прототипы рассматриваются в 9й главе.

Comment: @perfect, не спешите, просто читайте дальше.

Comment: Это введение еще автор ссылается что он объяснить все позже, а я не помню чтобы это уже встречалось мне раньше

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рекомендую ознакомиться вот с этим материалом: [Прототип объекта](https://learn.javascript.ru/prototype) - по ссылке очень грамотный и полезный источник знаний по Javascript.

Выдержка оттуда:

> Объекты в JavaScript можно организовать в цепочки так, чтобы свойство,
>   не найденное в одном объекте, автоматически искалось бы в другом.
>
> Связующим звеном выступает специальное свойство `__proto__`.
>
> Если один объект имеет специальную ссылку `__proto__` на другой объект,
>   то при чтении свойства из него, если свойство отсутствует в самом
>   объекте, оно ищется в объекте `__proto__`.
>
> Объект, на который указывает ссылка `__proto__`, называется
>   **«прототипом»**.

Answer (score 0):

Прототип - это отдалённый аналог парент класса из ООП. По сути - это указание объекту от кого свойства и функции он должен наследовать.

Comment: Это весьма отдалённый аналог ответа...

Comment: Он писался до обновления вопроса